# Django - Unique model data

Tags: django, unique, models, digital-signature, django-signals

For example:

```
class CarImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    message = models.TextField()


message = 'awesome car'
for image in Image.objects.all():
    for car in Car.objects.all():
        if not CarImage.objects.filter(
            Q(image=image), 
            Q(car=car), 
            Q(message=message),
            ):
            carimage = CarImage()
            carimage.image = image
            carimage.car = car
            carimage.message = message
            carimage.save()
```

Is there a more efficient way to create unique models based on multiple fields? Would a signature field make this better? Or would Django Signals fix the problem - whenever Car, Image, message is created send signal to create CarImage?

Comment: Am I correct that problem is that you have the Image and Car tables and need to populate new table CarImage based on existing data from two tables mentioned above? Could you provide model definition for CarImage ?

Comment: Correct, plus some arbitrary data like 'message'. I have to constantly check if any Image, Car, or message has been added to populate CarImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together) constraint in `CarImage` model `Meta`.

> Sets of field names that, taken together, must be unique.

Django will ensure that whenever you create a `CarImage` object, set of `image`, `car` and `message` fields taken together are unique.

```
class CarImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    message = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('image', 'car', 'message'),) # define unique_together constraint
```